# Closing a form from another project in same solution in visual basic

Tags: vb.net

I have two projects in the same solution in visual basic. I have no problem opening the form in the second project when I tick the checkbox, but I can't seem to get it to close when un-ticking. When I tick the checkbox, it just keeps opening a new form instead of closing it.

Here is my code:

```
    Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged
        Dim showTimerApp As New timerApp.TimerForm
        If CheckBox1.Checked = True Then
            showTimerApp.Show()
        ElseIf CheckBox1.Checked = False Then
            showTimerApp.Hide()
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: Because you're creating a new Instance of `TimerForm` each time you tick/untick that CheckBox. When you activate it, you create a new Instance and show it, when deselecting, you create a new Instance which is never shown and is not related to any existing Instance. Do you actually mean to create and show multiple Instances of that Form or do you want to have just one that preserves its current content? So you hide it instead of closing it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. No, I do not want multiple instances. I just want to have one that preserves the content and just hides it... I can't figure out how to make that happen.